# pandas plot mixing bars and lines

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby, python-datetime

I have the results from two groupby operations, the first one, `m_y_count`, in this multiindex format (first column years and second column months):

```
2007    12    39
2008    1     3
        2     120
2009    6     1000
2010    1     86575
        2     726212
        3     2987954
        4     3598215
        6     160597
```

and the other one, `y_count`, only has years:

```
2007    69
2008    3792
2009    5
2010    791
```

My question is: How do I plot them in the same figure, with different (log) y-axes, and `m_y_count` with bars while `y_count` with a line with marker?

My attempt:

```
ax = y_count.plot(kind="bar", color='blue', log = True)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
m_y_count.plot(kind="bar", color='red', alpha = 0.5, ax = ax2)
```

This produces the bars for both pandas Series, but when I try to change to `kind="line"` in the first line, no line appears.

Any hint on how to proceed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Edit:

I forgot you wanted one as bars.

Also, if you don't want to mess with all this `datetime` stuff, you can just plot the years as integers on the x-axis (with months being 1/12 fractions).  But I find that using `datetime` is pretty smart once you get everything as a time object.

---

I am not so familiar with plotting stuff straight out of `pandas`, but you can pretty easily do this in `matplotlib`.  I couldn't quite copy your data in, though: to follow the example below you would have to convert your multi-index to a single datetimeindex, which I think [would not be too hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53049663/pandas-multi-index-of-integers-to-datetime-index).

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

#making fake data
dates1 = pd.date_range('12-01-2007','06-01-2010',periods=9)
data1 = np.random.randint(0,3598215,9)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1,index=dates1,columns=['Values'])
dates2 = pd.date_range('01-01-2006',periods=4,freq='1Y') #i don't get why but this starts at the end of 2006, near 2007
df2 = pd.DataFrame([69,3000,5,791],index=dates2,columns=['Values'])

#plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(df2.index,df2['Values'],width=dt.timedelta(days=200),color='red',label='df2')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_ylabel('DF2 values',color='red')

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(df1.index,df1['Values'],color='blue',label='df1')
ax2.set_yscale('log',)
ax2.set_ylabel('DF1 values',color='blue')

years = mdates.YearLocator() #locate years for the ticks
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(years) #format the ticks to just show years
xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)

ax.legend(loc=0)
ax2.legend(loc=2)
```

[image]

I can elaborate if you can't port this to your case.

Comment: matplotlib is a workaround that I was trying to avoid, but it might work. However, how would you plot the second line with bars?

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks!